# Bash: Count number of occurrences for a particular string from multiple log.gz files

Tags: bash

As a title, I got several fairly large log.gz files in my folder. The size of these log.gz files is about 4GB each.

I am interested in the number of occurrences of a particular string, such as "abcdfg". What is the bash command I can perform counting calculations here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
zgrep -c 'abcdef' *.gz
```

or you could mention complete path for files and then use `*.gz` too in above code.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this command that will count occurrences of the `pattern` across the .gz files.

```
gunzip -c *.gz | grep 'pattern' | wc -l
```

Example:

```
# Say there are 3 .gz files with these contents:
a.txt.gz
a1
b2
c3

b.txt.gz
b1
b2
c3

cat c.txt.gz
a3
b3
c4

$ gunzip -c *.gz | grep 'b' | wc -l
4

$ gunzip -c *.gz | grep 'c3' | wc -l
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could count them all in parallel with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel zgrep -c "STRING" ::: *.gz
```

And then total those values with `awk`:

```
parallel zgrep -c "STRING" ::: *.gz | awk '{t+=$1} END{print t+0}'
```